# loading external JS libraries / modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a question regarding loading External JS files in Angular JS in terms of performance:

I have a small module which uses tinymce editor. 
I have installed it via bower ('angular-ui-tinymce') and it works fine.

Since I'm using this library rarely, and it is being loaded on app start every time - is it better (in terms of performance) to load it in index.html async / defer like this? (to avoid being a blocking script?)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-tinymce/0.0.19/tinymce.min.js" defer></script>
```

Is it possible to load external js files only when the user enters a specific module?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible by simply adding defer attribute to your script link.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff, why not? https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/

Comment: take a look at this file https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/blob/0.0.13/src/lazyload.js

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"performance"* in this case, you mean your bundling size I assume?

What you have to consider is if this is going to come up again down the road.
A handful of dependencies are best served when bundled together instead of several individual requests.

Even though it is not this case, if by any chance you were including dependencies that had to be configured during bootstrap they could not be asynchronously loaded.

So IMHO you want the best of both, you can always bundle and place your app on a CDN, free performance right there.

Comment: thanks, @Silver, I mean that the bundle will include only the "must" JS files to start with and keep it thin as possible. The other JS files, which are rarely being used and take a lot time to download, will be downloaded in the background. Preferably when the user enters a specific module, but its not a must thing. That's why I am asking - if I exclude from my bundle an big external library, and place it in async call - will it be better in initial loading time (i.e - "performance")?

Comment: If it not an async call, it will be a blocking script, so if you want to load it externally I would advise to make it async.
As for JS being loaded when in a specific module, it can also be done (although not be most elegant thing in the world)
I am not sure what bundling tool you are using, but webpack has `code splitting` which helps load JS on demand or in parallel so you can have smaller bundles and control resource load prioritization (load modules on demand)